# Isolate JavaScript function execution

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I could isolate the execution of a JavaScript function to avoid the browser to break.

Example: if I want to output in console an associative array with around 10k elements, the browser would stop responding. How can I avoid that?

Comment: So you want to run the code asynchronously?

Comment: Since Javascript is known to run in single thread, I hardly think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is a Web Worker.

A web worker is a JavaScript that runs in the background, independently of other scripts, without affecting the performance of the page. You can continue to do whatever you want: clicking, selecting things, etc., while the web worker runs in the background.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp